# How to generate the audio spectrum using fft in C++?

Tags: c++, audio, fft, spectrum

I want to generate an audio spectrum (as seen in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNT8Sn4IKbo)) of a mp3 audio file. Basically this problem requires calculating the fft of the audio signal. How do I program this in C/C++?

I've looked at a couple of open source libraries such as [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) and I really don't know how to use these for my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you already know C or C++?  If not, it's probably best to start off with something simpler...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604453/analyze-audio-using-fast-fourier-transform

Comment: Do you know anything about DSP?  FFTW is a fantastic tool, but unless you anything about Fourier transforms/windowing/resolution bins/etc. it will be very difficult to produce anything.

Comment: FFT is the easy part (and definitely not the last word) of power spectrum density estimation. There are many other considerations, especially windowing. Google `Slepian window` for robust techniques which minimize power leakage.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are quite a few similar/related questions on SO already which are well worth reading as the answers contain a lot of useful information and advice, but in essence you need to do this:

- Convert the audio data to the format required by FFT (e.g. int -> float, with separate L/R channels);
- Apply suitable [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_window) (e.g. [Hann aka Hanning window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hann_and_Hamming_windows))
- Apply FFT (NB: if using typical complex-to-complex FFT then set all imaginary parts in the input array to zero);
- Calculate the magnitude of the first N/2 FFT output bins (`sqrt(re*re + im*im)`);
- Optionally convert magnitude to dB (log) scale (`20 * log10(magnitude)` or `10 * log10(re*re + im*im)`);
- Plot N/2 (log) magnitude values.

Note that while FFTW is a very good and very fast FFT it may be a little overwhelming for a beginner - it's also very expensive if you want to include it as part of a commercial product. I recommend starting with [KissFFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) instead.

Comment: +1 - The only thing I'd add is a first step to separate the left (or right, doesn't matter) channel out from the audio file.  And another +1 if I could for using KissFFT before mucking with FFTW.

Comment: @mtrw: thanks for the comments - added note re separating L/R channels to the first step

Comment: I would only add that you can simplify if you're doing a log scale - instead of calculating magnitude (with sqrt) and then scaling `20*log10`, take the square of the magnitude (skipping the sqrt) and then scale `10*log10`. Mathematically equivalent, but saves an unnecessary `sqrt` call.

Comment: @Mark: yes, good point, you can go straight to dB without the sqrt if  you don't need the linear magnitude.

Comment: @PaulR What is separate L/R channels? I am a novice as far as FFTs go and I have started reading about this topic so am just curios?

Comment: It's just the left/right stereo channels that you get in most sound files or audio inputs - you need to process left and right channels separately.

Comment: Why is the magnitude of the frequency components being converted to dB using the Field quantity convention instead of as a Power quantity? I thought that acoustic intensity was measured as a power? That is, why 20 * log10(magnitude) instead of 10 * log10(magnitude)?

Comment: @A.Levy: well this is how I think of it: input signals are voltages, power is proportional to V^2, so to get power in dB it's 20*log10 rather than 10*log10.