# Very simple explanation for using FFT to find audio frequency changes

Tags: java, audio, fft, frequency-analysis

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of using FFT to calculate frequency changes. I've been scavenging through a ton of articles on this concept but it's still confusing me. I found a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675457/how-to-generate-the-audio-spectrum-using-fft-in-c) article about the steps to take to calculate the frequency, but I'm still a little bit confused on exactly what to do in Java.

Comment: It seems to me that you don't need to understand "the concept of using fft". You just need to find a ready-made FFT function and call it). The result will be a frequency response: [screenshot of FFT result in audio editor](https://yadi.sk/i/C-iNbFiXnncvm)

Comment: Try searching for this question over at dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to start way back with some general concepts.  An FFT is just a fast DFT.  A DFT uses Fourier decomposition on a set of sampled data.  So first you need to understand what a waveform is, what a sinusoid is, what a frequency is (and is not the same as a musical pitch), and how Fourier's theorem works to relate the two.  Then how to compute a DFT on a window of a sampled waveform, and how to interpret the complex result vector.  Then how to do it fast in Java.