# Audio signal processing using Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I have been on homework about audio signal processing. I have read some paper and am confused about a formula:[image]. The formula is used to process a 44100Hz, 16 bit, single channel audio. The audio has been preprocessed and is sliced into 1024 width frames. The `F(w)` is the FFT coefficients of each frame and `w with - above` is half of the frame rate, 22050.

I have searched a lot, most important [Analyze audio using Fast Fourier Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604453/analyze-audio-using-fast-fourier-transform). But I still can not understand it clearly. I have got the FFT coeffcients, with scipy and numpy, a 1024 width array. Then how do I perform the formula? Does it equal to the sum of 0 to 512 values of the array?

Hope anybody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried? We generally expect to see source code of you attempt.

Comment: and is F(w) *really* the FFT co-efficents of each frame?  Looks like a function to me.   It might be useful to see the equation for it.

Comment: I have searched a lot on Google and stackoverflow. I have given what I think is the most helpful resource to me. I have read the audio signal, preprocess it and slice it into frames. I have done FFT on the frames. It seems that what I have got is the FFT coefficients. But I don't know how to use the FFT coefficients to perform the formula. I also hope the `F(w)` is a equation. If it is, there is no need for me to come here. All the papers I read just tell me that `F(w)` is the FFT coefficients of each frame. @Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got a signal `x = [ x_1, x_2, ..., x_N ]` then you would compute the formula above in python (with scipy imported):

```
E = sum( abs(fft(x))[:len(x)/2]**2 ) / len(x)
```

About the normalization factor `N = len(x)` I'm not 100% sure — this depends on the exact implementation of the fft.

Comment: How about the dw and limits in the integral?

Comment: Actually that is what I think: I only get an array so the integration here is meaningless. Although papers all tell me that is an integration, but I do think what they mean is actually a sum.

Comment: Of course, integrals only exist in theory. Practically when dealing with real data you are always computing sums.