# Audio spectrum extraction from audio file by python

Tags: python, audio, beat-detection

Sorry if I submit a duplicate, but I wonder if there is any lib in python which makes you able to extract sound spectrum from audio files. I want to be able to take an audio file and write an algoritm which will return a set of data {TimeStampInFile; Frequency-Amplitude}.

I heard that this is usually called Beat Detection, but as far as I see beat detection is not a precise method, it is good only for visualisation, while I want to manipulate on the extracted data and then convert it back to an audio file. I don't need to do this real-time.

I will appreciate any suggestions and recommendations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can compute and visualize the spectrum and the spectrogram this using scipy, for this test i used this audio file: [vignesh.wav](https://github.com/MTG/essentia-audio/raw/master/recorded/vignesh.wav)

```
from scipy.io import wavfile # scipy library to read wav files
import numpy as np

AudioName = "vignesh.wav" # Audio File
fs, Audiodata = wavfile.read(AudioName)

# Plot the audio signal in time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(Audiodata)
plt.title('Audio signal in time',size=16)

# spectrum
from scipy.fftpack import fft # fourier transform
n = len(Audiodata) 
AudioFreq = fft(Audiodata)
AudioFreq = AudioFreq[0:int(np.ceil((n+1)/2.0))] #Half of the spectrum
MagFreq = np.abs(AudioFreq) # Magnitude
MagFreq = MagFreq / float(n)
# power spectrum
MagFreq = MagFreq**2
if n % 2 > 0: # ffte odd 
    MagFreq[1:len(MagFreq)] = MagFreq[1:len(MagFreq)] * 2
else:# fft even
    MagFreq[1:len(MagFreq) -1] = MagFreq[1:len(MagFreq) - 1] * 2 

plt.figure()
freqAxis = np.arange(0,int(np.ceil((n+1)/2.0)), 1.0) * (fs / n);
plt.plot(freqAxis/1000.0, 10*np.log10(MagFreq)) #Power spectrum
plt.xlabel('Frequency (kHz)'); plt.ylabel('Power spectrum (dB)');


#Spectrogram
from scipy import signal
N = 512 #Number of point in the fft
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(Audiodata, fs,window = signal.blackman(N),nfft=N)
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(t, f,10*np.log10(Sxx)) # dB spectrogram
#plt.pcolormesh(t, f,Sxx) # Lineal spectrogram
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [seg]')
plt.title('Spectrogram with scipy.signal',size=16);

plt.show()
```

i tested all the code and it works, you need, numpy, matplotlib and scipy.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the script! Just add "import numpy as np" at the top to make it work.

Comment: Get those Errors:

```RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  plt.plot(freqAxis/1000.0, 10*np.log10(MagFreq)) #Power spectrum
Traceback (most recent call last):
packages/scipy/signal/_spectral_py.py", line 1971, in _triage_segments
    raise ValueError('window is longer than input signal')
ValueError: window is longer than input signal
dirk.schiller@C02DT9UMML7H scipy % 
````

Answer (score 11):

I think your question has three separate parts:

1. How to load audio files into python?
2. How to calculate spectrum in python?
3. What to do with the spectrum?

**1. How to load audio files in python?**

You are probably best off by using `scipy`, as it provides a lot of signal processing functions. For loading audio files:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

samplerate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read("mywav.wav")
```

Now you have the sample rate (samples/s) in `samplerate` and data as a `numpy.array` in `data`. You may want to transform the data into floating point, depending on your application.

There is also a standard python module `wave` for loading wav-files, but `numpy`/`scipy` offers a simpler interface and more options for signal processing.

**2. How to calculate the spectrum**

Brief answer: Use FFT. For more words of wisdom, see:

[Analyze audio using Fast Fourier Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604453/analyze-audio-using-fast-fourier-transform/604756#604756)

Longer answer is quite long. Windowing is very important, otherwise you'll have strange spectra.

**3. What to do with the spectrum**

This is a bit more difficult. Filtering is often performed in time domain for longer signals. Maybe if you tell us what you want to accomplish, you'll receive a good answer for this one. Calculating the frequency spectrum is one thing, getting meaningful results with it in signal processing is a bit more complicated.

(I know you did not ask this one, but I see it coming with a probability >> 0. Of course, it may be that you have good knowledge on audio signal processing, in which case this is irrelevant.)

Comment: Thanks, that was realy helpfull. I plan to write a software using scikit-learn or PyBrain which will analyze audiofiles and try to determine to which music genere it belongs to.

Comment: Late to the party, but given your goal (write a library to classify music genres) you could take a look at this https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis