# Extracting features from audio signal

Tags: python, librosa

I have just started to work on data in the form of audio. I am using librosa as a tool. My project requires me to extract features like:

- Total duration of the audio
- Minimum Intensity of the audio signal
- Maximum Intensity of the audio signal
- Mean Intensity of the audio signal
- Jitter
- Rate of speaking
- Number of Pauses
- Maximum Duration of Pauses
- Average Duration of Pauses
- Total Duration of Pauses

Although, I know about these terms but I have no idea how to extract these from an audio file. Are these inbuilt in some form in the `librosa.feature` variable? Or we need to manually calculate these? Can someone guide me how to proceed?

I know that this job can be performed using softwares like Praat, but I need to do it in python.

> Praat can be used for spectral analysis (spectrograms), pitch
>   analysis, formant analysis, intensity analysis, jitter, shimmer, and
>   voice breaks.

Comment: You can start reading the documentation https://librosa.github.io/librosa/

Comment: I have already gone through the doc and turned to SO only because the doc didn't help me.

Comment: `import scipy.io.wavfile` https://stackoverflow.com/a/24391521/1755108

Comment: @brokenfoot can you please explain how to use the obtained data? I got a bit of hint but it would be really helpful if you could throw some more light.

Comment: For eg to get duration, `scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)` gives you 1. rate ie samples/sec, and 2. samples. You can calculate duration by `$2/$1`..

Comment: can you please explain the same for `number of pauses`? actually the function returns a 2d numpy array and i am not able to understand the contents of that array. is it intensity/ frequency/ something else?

Comment: It's 2-d array because it is dual channel. You can access each channel as `data[:,0]`, `data[:,1]`. Data is intensity, not frequency - you need FFT to get frequency. To get no of pauses, you need to define what a pause is. I don't think there is a function in scipy that look at the audio and detect pauses in it.