# What do i need to be create an audio visualizer in c# with unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, visualizer

I need an audio  visualizer , the best i found made by unity

- I want to know how to make an audio visualizer like this link in unity or something like that
  [enter link description here](https://www.toneden.io/kurt-creations/post/nocopyrightsounds-audio-visualizer-improved-version-free-audio-spectrum-template)

Comment: Learn about FFTs. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604453/analyze-audio-using-fast-fourier-transform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't very specific, but if you are looking for a simple audio visualizer tutorial I personally followed this one and it worked really well. It shows you how to gather the audio data from a song, and of course you decide how to display it.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pmoP1ZOoNs

Hope it helps!